# Logging in a separate thread in QuickFIX C++

Tags: quickfix

In QuickFIX C++, is the logging to a file blocking or it is done in a separate thread?

If it is blocking, is there a configuration parameter to make it async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QuickFIX FileLog is not asynchronous and there's no configuration setting to make it so. However, it's not difficult to implement your own Log implementation with that behavior (possibly integrating an existing logging framework that does support asynchronous logging). Look at the existing Log implementations to see how to do this.

Comment: Would you please elaborate more about this asynchronous logging for QuickFIX? As far as I know, more logging framework is synchronous, like log4j/slf4j?